# Django + SpatiaLite + srid + distance queries

Tags: python, django, geodjango, spatialite, srid

I am trying to do simple geodjango app, which contains list of shops, and when you put an address in it it returns closest shops to your location.

I am following tutorial which used PostgreSQL and Postgis, but I want to use SQLite and SpatiaLite (I want to use it later in another app which uses SQLite, so I don't know if I won't mess up, if I try to change it into PostgreSQL. I don't usually work with Python nor SQLite nor PostgreSQL)

I have a problem when I try to make a query and count the distance.

In my <kbd>models.py</kbd> I have:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from django.contrib.gis import geos
from django.db import models

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = gis_models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude", geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    gis = gis_models.GeoManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
```

And in <kbd>views.py</kbd> I have function:

```
def get_shops(longitude, latitude):
    current_point = geos.fromstr("POINT(%s %s)" % (longitude, latitude))
    distance_from_point = {'km': 10}
    shops = models.Shop.gis.filter(location__distance_lte=(current_point, measure.D(**distance_from_point)))
    shops = shops.distance(current_point).order_by('distance')
    return shops.distance(current_point)
```

I get error:

> SQLite does not support linear distance calculations on geodetic coordinate systems.

I've read about SRID, I guess that I should change my model. But I have no idea how to write it down. And there is a possibility that it's there is a problem with how I try to get the sorted data.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think one problem is in your models.py
Your model manager is still the default model manager. 
Your model should look something like this.</del>

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis import geos


class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude", geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

<del>So this model is associate with the geodjango model-manager.  It's also not required to import modelfields from different sources.</del>

The other problem `SQLite does not support linear distance calculations on geodetic coordinate systems` you can rid of if you set your srid to something like 4326 (WGS84). Some more information you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526928/geodjango-what-srid-to-use-for-pointfield-interfacing-with-google-maps-v3-api).
Or you implement your own distance calculation based on triangulation. 
Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703975/django-sort-by-distance) for some further explanation.

Comment: I have two managers, and they work. I have changed: PointField(u"longitude/latitude", geography=True, blank=True, null=True) into: PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True), and I can add shops, but it still does not support linear distance calculations. When I change SRID to 3857 then sorting by distance works, but adding does not.

Comment: sure, my mistake. I had overseen this line `models.Shop.gis.filter(location__distance_lte=(current_point, measure.D(**distance_from_point)))` where you query the correct filter. So the problem isn't the model. I update my answer